Is it possible to run 3 independent switch/ light combos in series?
This is actually kind of two questions in one:
I'm running a 15 AMP, 14-3 wire to power three rooms' lights in a single area of my home. This is all new work. In terms of total estimated load, it will be 9 LEDs, so very minimal. My end goal is that each room has its own switch that controls the lights in that room.
The reason I'm running 14-3 is because it was more cost-effective since I'll be using it for another room that will actually utilize 3-way switching. This particular room will not be 3-way switches, so I can simply end the red wire if it's not needed.
I know that I could put in a junction box and split the power between the three switches and the lights they'll control, but...
...question 1: Is it a negligible difference to run these lines in series vs. parallel when dealing with such low demand?
If it's better to run them in series, question 2: how would you connect these in series such that power can run along the line while each switch is also able to control the power to the lights?
I realize the answer might be "Just run them in parallel," in which case, I'm good to know how to do that. TIA.


Is the power running from the panel to switches, or to the light boxes first?

@crip659 panel to switch #1, as shown in my image

Switches and lights are to be independent of each, right—not some kind of 3- or 4-way setup?

@Huesmann correct, each light should only be controlled by a single switch.

It may depend a bit on the physical layout as well.  But ordinarily I think you'd run the power wire to the first switch box, nut each wire to the cable to the next switch in line.  Pigtail the hot and ground to your switch, and connect the bulb hot to the other terminal on the switch.  Nut the bulb neutral to the other neutrals (same for bulb ground).

@Huesmann so is it desirable to run them in series then? From a wiring perspective it seems much simpler to run them in parallel, but if series is better in any way, I'll do what you described. Again it's only like 9 LEDs.

You can probably do either.  Like I said, it depends on the layout.  If you have each switch 50' apart, that's 150' of wire between them vs. 100'.  You may not care about the cost of wire.  The benefit of parallel is that troubleshooting may be easier.

14/2 is hot(black), neutral(white) and unmentioned ground.  14/3 will have an extra hot wire which you do not really need, if running power to the switches.  Not for LEDs anyway.
